# Login to Windows Authentication automatically

Tags: authentication, iis, windows-authentication

We have a program that runs in IIS with Windows authentication, and which is available to the outside world.

Right now, we provide to every interested party a link to the program, along with guest credentials they then have to type.

Is there a possibility to do away with the credentials? Our internal people should be able to login as usual, but we want to provide a link to get into the guest account without typing any login credentials.

I have tried to add the credentials into the clickable url, but Internet Explorer and Edge browser do not support this, and Mobile Safari throws phishing warnings.

Can this be done universally, that the authentication is done invisibly in the background in all browsers, using some kind of redirect or XHR call with arguments or something like that?

Comment: Short answer: no, not invisibly in all browsers.   Your Mac users will never have a seamless experience, but your Windows users can, and in fact ASP.NET comes with it built-in via the Windows Authentication option.

Comment: @Paul Windows Authentication does not help external users, who are not part of our organization AD.

Comment: I agree, but it's the only way to do it seamlessly.  Everything else that isn't just wide open requires some form of credentials and/or SSO redirects.

Comment: @Paul The guest account should be just wide open, but the application should still allow our internal users to authenticate.

Comment: Ok... so what's the problem?  You should provide more information about how your app is built & what the problem is; what you're describing doesn't sound like a problem at all for any application I've worked on.